# Cannot resolve symbol 'makeText'

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use makeText() in Second Activity. But it says "Cannot reolve symbol 'makeText' " I tried changing context to **this**, **getApplicationContext()** but nothing worked.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        String[] Listofmobiles = {"Samsung", "Nokia","IPhone","Oppo","Vivo"};



        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listviewtext,Listofmobiles);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.lvmobile);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast toast = new Toast.makeText(this,"I will buy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `Try this one`

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity2.this,"I will buy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Comment: But why not 'new' ?

Comment: because .makeText is static method of Toast  class so you don't need to assign memory using new key word. i hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `new`.

This is what you need:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(),"I will buy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

makeText is a static method. Use like this `Toast.makeText()`, not `new Toast.makeText()`